# Why is 田 read as だ instead of た/でん in 山田?

Tags: readings, rendaku, multiple-readings

When looking up 田 on [Jisho.org/田](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%94%B0%20%23kanji), it states it's readings as た and でん, but when the kanji is used in the family name Yamada (山田), the reading obviously changes to 'da'/だ.

Is this something you just 'have to know'? Or why isn't the fellow called Yamata?

Comment: This is called _rendaku_ and you can read about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku).

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I didn't know how to search for this effect without giving the example. The linked question answers my issue perfectly. Thank you